# Where is a list of Error Codes for derby db?

Tags: java, sql, exception, error-handling, derby

I am using derby DB.  I am trying to shutdown the database. I am receiving:

```
----- SQLException -----
SQL State:  XJ004
Error Code: 40000
Message:    Database '<db name>' not found.
```

I could find the SQL states listed here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefexcept71493.html

It lists `XJ004: Database '<databaseName>' not found.`

However, I can't find a list of Error Codes for derby.

Where is the list of error codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derby uses the error code in the SQLException to express the exception [severity](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/reference/sqlj169.html).

> The JDBC driver returns SQLExceptions for all errors from Derby. If
>   the exception originated in a user type but is not itself an
>   SQLException, it is wrapped in an SQLException. Derby-specific
>   SQLExceptions use SQLState class codes starting with X. Standard
>   SQLState values are returned for exceptions where appropriate.
>
> Derby database exceptions are classified by severity. The severity of
>   an SQLException is available through the getErrorCode method call on
>   the SQLException. The severities are summarized below. For more
>   information, check the javadoc for
>   org.apache.derby.types.ExceptionSeverity:

The constants are:

```
/**
 * NO_APPLICABLE_SEVERITY occurs only when the system was
 * unable to determine the severity.
 */
public static final int NO_APPLICABLE_SEVERITY = 0;
/**
 * WARNING_SEVERITY is associated with SQLWarnings.
 */
public static final int WARNING_SEVERITY = 10000;
/**
 * STATEMENT_SEVERITY is associated with errors which
 * cause only the current statement to be aborted.
 */
public static final int STATEMENT_SEVERITY = 20000;
/**
 * TRANSACTION_SEVERITY is associated with those errors which
 * cause the current transaction to be aborted.
 */
public static final int TRANSACTION_SEVERITY = 30000;
/**
 * SESSION_SEVERITY is associated with errors which
 * cause the current connection to be closed.
 */
public static final int SESSION_SEVERITY = 40000;
/**
 * DATABASE_SEVERITY is associated with errors which
 * cause the current database to be closed.
 */
public static final int DATABASE_SEVERITY = 45000;
/**
 * SYSTEM_SEVERITY is associated with internal errors which
 * cause the system to shut down.
 */
public static final int SYSTEM_SEVERITY = 50000;
```